# Find every time a word appears in an array and return the text from the corresponding cell three rows up from it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a function that searches an array (C4:G53) and looks for every occurrence of a word, in this case, "Orientation", in the rows labelled "Project" (i.e. Row 7, 12, 17, 22, etc.), but then takes the word in the cell 3 rows up from this occurrence and joins all such cases in a string of text. So, in this case, it would return "Fractions, Algebra, Decimals".

[image: See example sheet.]

Is there a quick way to do this?

I have tried using `TEXTJOIN()` and `IF` but only seem to be able to achieve this by comparing single rows at a time, so to check the entire array (and eventually the intention is to also check across other sheets), it is becoming quite lengthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls. try this formula with TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A7:F36="Orientation",OFFSET(A7:F36,-3,0),""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula:

```vb
=LET(d,C4:H18,
c,TOCOL(d,1,TRUE),
f,FILTER(DROP(c,-1),DROP(c,1)="Orientation"),
TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,f))
```

The trick is to rebuild the whole range as a column - omitting the empty rows.

And then filter the result by an offset of "itself" ...

-- **edit** --

If there is content e.g. for row Leader above formula will fail (as it expects those rows to be empty as in the screenshot provided).

Then use this formula:

```vb
=LET(d,C4:H18,
c,TOCOL(d,0,TRUE),
rowSelection,SEQUENCE(15,,1,5),
f,FILTER(CHOOSEROWS(c,rowSelection),CHOOSEROWS(c,rowSelection+3)="Orientation"),
TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,f))
```

It takes every 5th row (= Title) and every 8th row (= Project) to filter the generated column.

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup in Matching Rows

**Rows Per Class (5)**

Based on the *return* sequence (`rs`) `1,6,11...`.

```
=LET(search_val,"Orientation",data,C4:G53,rof,3,rpc,5,
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)/rpc,,,rpc),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)),
    TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(INDEX(data,rs+rof,cs)=search_val,
        INDEX(data,rs,cs),"")))
```

**Row Labels ("Project:")**

Based on the *search* sequence (`ss`) `4,9,14...`.

```
=LET(search_val,"Orientation",data,C4:G53,rData,A4:A53,rl,"Project:",rof,3,
    ss,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),rData=rl),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)),
    TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(INDEX(data,ss,cs)=search_val,
        INDEX(data,ss-rof,cs),"")))
```

[image]

**Developer (Study) Mode**

- Replace the `r` (result) with any of the other variables.
- Place the resulting cell to the right of the table so it can freely spill.

```
=LET(search_val,"Orientation",data,C4:G53,rof,3,rpc,5,
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)/rpc,,,rpc),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)),
    ds,INDEX(data,rs+rof,cs),
    dr,INDEX(data,rs,cs),
    r,TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ds=search_val,dr,"")),
    r)
```

```
=LET(search_val,"Orientation",data,C4:G53,rData,A4:A53,rl,"Project:",rof,3,
    ss,FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),rData=rl),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)),
    ds,INDEX(data,ss,cs),
    dr,INDEX(data,ss-rof,cs),
    r,TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ds=search_val,dr,"")),
    r)
```

**Down the Rabbit Hole**

- Here are some ideas, among others, the *"check across other sheets"* one.

```
=LET(rData,INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!"&"A4:A53"),
        data,INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!"&"C4:G53"),
        svalue,B7,slookup,B4,sreturn,B5,info,O3:O7,
    rpc,ROWS(info),
    s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)/rpc,,,rpc),
    ss,s-1+XMATCH(slookup,info),
    rs,s-1+XMATCH(sreturn,info),
    cs,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)),
    ds,INDEX(data,ss,cs),
    dr,INDEX(data,rs,cs),
    r,TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ds=svalue,dr,"")),
    r)
```

[image]

- The *Information* list needs to be in the same order as the order in the *Subject* sheets.
- Note that `History` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a sheet name.